# Indentation of a block in beamer

Tags: beamer, indentation, block

I'm facing problem with indenting a paragraph in beamer. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\indent ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddd
ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
dddddddddddddddddddddddd
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to indent just the first line of the paragraph or do you want to move the whole paragraph?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, only the first line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) sets the paragraph indent to `0pt` by default (in [`beamerbasemisc.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasemisc.sty)). So, using `\indent` doesn't have any effect, nor does `\hspace*{\parindent}`. You can use `\hspace*{20pt}` though:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\indent ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddd % No indentation
ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
dddddddddddddddddddddddd
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\hspace*{\parindent}ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddd % No indentation
ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
dddddddddddddddddddddddd
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\hspace*{20pt}ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddd % Forced 20pt indent
ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
dddddddddddddddddddddddd
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

A `20pt` paragraph indentation is the default setting for LaTeX (see [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)).

Comment: It worked only for the first line in the frame. After \linebreak the indentation is back to default.

Answer (score 2):

Because I do prefer to have `\indent` work in beamer like it does in my article class (and others), I have the following in my preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace*{2em}}
```

This allows `\indent` to behave as I expect.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!